# Not receiving email in user object when authenticating with facebook

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularfire to authenticate users via facebook. I get the user object, which contains a property called thirdPartyUserData. The basic information is in here, but email is not.

I have included email in the scope

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function() {
        login.$login('facebook', { rememberMe: true, scope: 'email' })
            .then(function(user) {
                console.log(user);
            }
});

.factory('login', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://housemates.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
});
```

When the login pops up, it asks me if I am happy to give my email, so I know that part is working, but nothing email related shows anywhere in the user object.

```
Object {uid: "facebook:NUMBERS", provider: "facebook", id: "NUMBERS", displayName: "Jim Jansonby", thirdPartyUserData: Object…}accessToken: "TOKEN"displayName: "Jim Jansonby"firebaseAuthToken: "TOKEN"id: "NUMBERS"provider: "facebook"thirdPartyUserData: Objectage_range: Objectmin: 21__proto__: Objectfirst_name: "Jim"gender: "female"id: "NUMBERS"last_name: "Jansonby"link: "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/NUMBERS/"locale: "en_GB"name: "Jim Jansonby"picture: Objecttimezone: 1__proto__: Objectuid: "facebook:NUMBERS"__proto__: Object
```

Versions

- Chrome 37.0.2062.124 / OSX 10.10
- Firebase ~1.1.0
- Angularfire ~0.8.2
- SimpleLogin ~1.6.4
- Not using ionic or cordova, just running on desktop

Comment: Hi Tom. Can you include enough info here to reproduce this issue? That typically means version info for browser/os/firebase/angularfire etc. If you are using Ionic/Cordova or any other intermediaries, that would also be significant.

Comment: @Kato I've added some more detail to the question

Comment: Thanks, Tom, only thing missing is SimpleLogin, which I'll presume is included in the mix?

Comment: @Kato Ah yes, added that as well

Comment: I just [gave this a try in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/bjayjgur/) and could not repro. If I log in with Facebook it shows my email in third party data. I think you'll find that a) you need to log out of facebook or b) your account has set the email to private so it can't be viewed by third parties.

Comment: @Kato This must be it. Not sure why though, I just set up a fresh account and didn't make any changes to privacy settings. Works with an open graph test user though. Is there any error when requests for data aren't supplied?

Comment: I can't say. Sorry. All I can tell from here is that it's something in Facebook's side of the equation. Which is unfortunate; something at our end would be much easier to isolate and correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I have to say, firebase has been immensely impressive so far.